# Why materialiaze css collapsible is initialized in setTimeout while using with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

I was trying to initialize materialize css collapsible in angular7 but I was unable to get the instance of the element but when i tried same in setTimeout method it worked properly. Please anyone tell me why?

Comment: This is issue of component lifecycle Hook. Try to use ngAfterViewInit. Better you can post your code.
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: That is the problem of life cycle hook in angular. May be you are trying to access the DOM before initialize. Share your component code or try "ngAfterViewInit" lifecycle hook.